# Html button with id and type

Tags: html

How can I do this. I want that my button have ID and TYPE attributs.. is that posible?

```html
<input name="proccess" type="submit" class="invisible" value="1" />
<button id="send-form" TYPE="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary top-margin">Pošalji</button>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kEuJ9)

And if it is not possible what can i do to create that.

Comment: Pardon? I really have no clue what you want.

Comment: you already have them in ur html....what is the problem...Aren't they working?

Comment: Your button already has id and type attribute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kEuJ9/ Here is jsfiddle  When you click on button 1 that check for errors and button 2 send email.. i want that all in one button .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have an id and type attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have not included `.js` file in ur fiddle & Try the following :-

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="post">
```